# troubles with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

How to use method as parameter in `InvokeMember`?
I mean

without reflection

```
ContainerEvents ems = new ContainerEvents();
Test ob1 = new Test(4);
Exam ob2 = new Exam(1);
FExam ob3 = new FExam(1);
Check ob4 = new Check(5);
ems.Setplus = new Super(ob1.Write);
ems.Setplus = new Super(ob2.Write);
ems.Setplus = new Super(ob3.Write);
ems.Setplus = new Super(ob4.Write);
ems.Run();
```

Super is a delegate.

with reflection I want to do the same thing

```
Type type1 = typeof (Test);
Type type2 = typeof (Exam);
Type type3 = typeof (FExam);
Type type4 = typeof (Check);
Type events = typeof (ContainerEvents);
object eventer = Activator.CreateInstance(events);
events.InvokeMember("Setplus",BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,null,eventer,)
```

But I don't know what to send as parameter. Create instance of `Super` object?

Setplus is a property

```
public Super Setplus
{
    set { obj.activate += value; }
}
```

obj - object of class Event

```
public class Event
{
    public event Super activate ;
    public void act()
    {
        if (activate != null) activate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use invoke member? In the original code you're only invoking `Run()`, after putting a few sets into Setplus. Your code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do, and therefore hard to help you. Edit the code to have logical names and with examples we can be familiar with.

Comment: (Please use spaces instead of tabs when presenting code on Stack Overflow - Markdown doesn't really like tabs much...)

Comment: it's a lab so it doesn't have much sense. ok. the idea is to use reflection to call methods,create objects and etc. how to invoke propety in this case?

Comment: Duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090974/how-to-convert-delegate-to-object-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of:

```
ContainerEvents ems = new ContainerEvents();
Test ob1 = new Test(4);
ems.Setplus = new Super(ob1.Write);
```

Is this:

```
object ems = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ContainerEvents));
object ob1 = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Test), new object[] { 4 });
object super = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Super), ob1, "Write");
ems.GetType().GetProperty("SetPlus").SetValue(ems, super, null);
```